# WordPress: Deadlock on some queries without transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mariadb

Recently, durning a higher traffic I started to get these PHP errors:

```
Got error 'PHP message: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
INSERT INTO `wp_48_cf7dbplugin_submits` (`submit_time`, `form_name`, `field_name`, `field_value`, `field_order`) VALUES ('1641679333.361248', 'order', 'y_flat', '10', '8')

require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->parse_request, do_action_ref_array('parse_request'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, rest_api_loaded, WP_REST_Server->serve_request, WP_REST_Server->dispatch, WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request, WPCF7_REST_Controller->create
_feedback, WPCF7_ContactForm->submit, WPCF7_Submission::get_instance, WPCF7_Submission->proceed, WPCF7_Submission->before_send_mail, do_action_ref_array('wpcf7_before_send_mail'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, CFDBIntegrationContactForm7->saveFormData, CF7DBPlugin->saveFormData
```

And this continues for a few, **but not all**, more queries. It is WordPress with WPCF7DB plugin.

I checked and there is no transactions in WordPress or the plugin whatsoever.

The plugin iterates through each field and then uses simple `wpdb::prepare` and `wpdb::query` combination:

```php
$parametrizedQuery = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` (`submit_time`, `form_name`, `field_name`, `field_value`, `field_order`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)";

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($parametrizedQuery,
  $time,
  $title,
  $nameClean,
  $valueClean,
  $order++));
}
```

Table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `wp_48_cf7dbplugin_submits` (
  `submit_time` decimal(16,6) NOT NULL,
  `form_name` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_name` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` longblob DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `submit_time_idx` (`submit_time`),
  KEY `form_name_idx` (`form_name`),
  KEY `field_name_idx` (`field_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

What is strange that it only happens for a few fields in the loop that are different each time.

The database engine is 5.5.5-10.5.9-MariaDB-1:10.5.9+maria~buster with PHP 7.4.

Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

engine status report:

```
=====================================
2022-01-10 13:27:13 0x7fd4b0066700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 69 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 95869 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 20734661 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 20829772
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 30716
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 16274
RW-shared spins 274138, rounds 2338467, OS waits 886
RW-excl spins 952, rounds 16506, OS waits 360
RW-sx spins 102, rounds 1188, OS waits 34
Spin rounds per wait: 8.53 RW-shared, 17.34 RW-excl, 11.65 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 4055001
Purge done for trx's n:o < 4055001 undo n:o < 0 state: running
History list length 10
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 422025324769496, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
Pending normal aio reads:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
37144192 OS file reads, 2402390 OS file writes, 2249175 OS fsyncs
21.38 reads/s, 16372 avg bytes/read, 1.22 writes/s, 1.28 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 17, free list len 77, seg size 95, 3690 merges
merged operations:
 insert 136065, delete mark 309, delete 171
discarded operations:
 insert 9389, delete mark 13, delete 13
0.00 hash searches/s, 4840.34 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 5800939056
Log flushed up to   5800939056
Pages flushed up to 5773682207
Last checkpoint at  5773682207
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
2147483 log i/o's done, 1.22 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 167772160
Dictionary memory allocated 3290232
Buffer pool size   8065
Free buffers       0
Database pages     8065
Old database pages 2957
Modified db pages  2027
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 25.130
Max dirty pages percent: 90.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0
Pages made young 1979022, not young 1458024765
21.80 youngs/s, 2893.80 non-youngs/s
Pages read 37142927, created 257902, written 250427
21.38 reads/s, 0.06 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 998 / 1000, young-making rate 1 / 1000 not 149 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 8065, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[1474]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=0, Main thread ID=0, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 26238521, updated 97796, deleted 3496, read 1479166152
1.13 inserts/s, 0.01 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 4830.65 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 48, updated 0, deleted 48, read 101
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: Deadlocks are a user application thing to resolve. This [percona article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/10/28/how-to-deal-with-mysql-deadlocks/) describes it. `show create table wp_48_cf7dbplugin_submits` and details of the other transaction in the conflict are needed. Also is this the insert in your question the only statement in the SQL transaction? Can you include the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` bit about last detected deadlock?

Comment: @danblack There are around 25 inserts with this query per form submission. The thing that bugs me the most is that the transaction is never started in the code. Can this be due to autocommit being on? I updated my question with the table structure, will add innodb status as soon as I get permission to use the query

Comment: I suggest to define an autoincrement primary key on that table. Those fake deadlocks are a mystery, but in the past I already witnessed them in an application which used client-generated UUID as primary keys, and they were gone with server-generated autoincrements. If you do not define primary key, Innodb will define something implicit, and this something might not be as well battle-tested, as autoincrement primary keys. Besides,  primary key is just right thing to have, even if you do not  use them now, you might in the future.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub Thanks, I will probably do that. The plugin's support is dropped anyways. I tried to wrap the whole loop into an actual transaction but the error is still occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to these fake deadlocks was to create a primary, auto increment key for the table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_48_cf7dbplugin_submits ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key;
```